# S3-backed java.io.File

Tags: java, amazon-s3

Here's my use case for a S3-backed Java `File`

```
File videoFile = new File(OUTPUT_FOLDER + "channel" + channel + "-" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4");
AWTSequenceEncoder encoder = AWTSequenceEncoder.createSequenceEncoder(videoFile, Long.valueOf(FPS).intValue());
 for (BufferedImage image : bufferedImages) {
      encoder.encodeImage(image);
}
```

Above is just one use-case, I am wondering if there exists a S3-backed `File` that can be used as a snap-in replacement for `java.io.File`; in the example code above the idea is to replace the `videoFile` of instead of persisting to disk, it will persist directly to S3 or S3-compatible storage.

And which is the best place to *inject* it, through compile-time or run-time?

Comment: Might be possible, but it's going to be a very limited `File` object that can't seek unless it persists the data locally first.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, no such thing exists.

The best you could do would be to implement an S3-backed file system at the operating system level.  (For example, using `s3backer` [linux man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/s3backer.1.html))  If the file system had the right properties, applications that used `java.io.File` wouldn't know the difference.

Alternatively, use a custom Java 7+ `FileSystem` [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html), but you will have to change your code to stop using `File` and start using the more modern APIs.

<sup>(Of course, if you were willing to dive in and modify the JVM at the native code level, anything would be possible.  But then you are introducing a whole stack of other problems.)</sup>

---

> And which is the best place to inject it, through compile-time or run-time?

That is not a viable option.  The important parts of `java.io.File` are implemented in native code in the JVM and are not "plugable" or "injectable".

Comment: Another important use case I have is for some DB that uses java.io.File to persist database data. One good example is https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus
A very powerful database in terms of transactions but still uses `java.io.File` that limits its ability to be used in a scalable environment.

Comment: Well yea ... so talk to the developers :-)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a snap-in S3 replacement for `java.io.File` per se but there is a `FileSystemProvider` SPI that can be used as a provider on the JVM class path that will allow you to do things like use `java.nio.Channel`s and `Path`s to access S3 objects via the URIs as if they were files. Take a look at https://github.com/awslabs/aws-java-nio-spi-for-s3

Answer (score 0):

There actually exists an *S3File* (or was) from https://packages.atlassian.com/maven/com/squeakysand/aws/squeakysand-aws-s3/

Upon researching, the author is a previous AWS Architect, the project now seems to be abandoned, but the license is under Apache so a good fork might be able to revive it.

As for answering the best place to *inject* the S3File, the answer is compile-time. However, it might be quite intrusive to the base source code as such:

```
S3File videoFile = new S3File(BUCKET_NAME, fileKey);
AWTSequenceEncoder encoder = AWTSequenceEncoder.createSequenceEncoder(videoFile, Long.valueOf(FPS).intValue());
 for (BufferedImage image : bufferedImages) {
      encoder.encodeImage(image);
}
```

Something like this would work.

In fact, it should work with the `S3File` having the exact same parameters as of `java.io.File` so it can be used as `S3File videoFile = new S3File(fileName);`

Where the bucket name and other connection is already in the constructor.